# Printing Images on two sides of a page so that they line up

Tags: graphics, printing

is there an easy way to line up two images with the same dimensions such that when the two images are printed they are back to back on the printed page and can be cut out of the piece of paper to create a double sided card?

Comment: This depends on the document class, geometry and whether there is anything else on the page.  If all you want is the images back to back, use standalone class.

Comment: It it just to set equal left and right margin, placing the first image at the upper left margin of page 1, and the second image on the upper right margin at page two. If the images are of similar size, they will print back to back.

Comment: `\begin{center}...\end{center}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an MWE. I use rule to substitute an image. If you print this document on a printer with the possibility to print on both side of the paper, you will have the the images at the same place, just to be cut out:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{5cm}{5cm}

\raggedleft\pagebreak

\rule{5cm}{5cm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using standalone is slightly more complicated than my comment indicated.

```
\documentclass[multi=wrapper]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newenvironment{wrapper}{\ignorespaces}{\unskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapper}
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{wrapper}

\begin{wrapper}
  \includegraphics{example-image-b}
\end{wrapper}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use the `center` environment. This works also for two-sided documents with different inner and outer margins.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\end{center}

\newpage

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```