# standalone's multi option doesn't crop page's content

Tags: standalone, crop

The `standalone` documentation claims:

> If [the `multi`] option is activated multiple pages are supported. Each page will be cropped to its content plus the selected border (as long either `preview` or `crop` are enabled).

But the following MCE:

```
\documentclass[multi,crop]{standalone}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

leads to a full A4 page. What's going on?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516221/printing-images-on-two-sides-of-a-page-so-that-they-line-up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare and wrap the desired code within a `\standaloneenv`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[multi,crop]{standalone}

\standaloneenv{multipage}

\begin{document}
\begin{multipage}
Test
\end{multipage}
\begin{multipage}
Test
\end{multipage}
\begin{multipage}
Test
\end{multipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the record, the environment's name doesn't matter: it could be e.g. `foo`. And, if one doesn't want horizontal spaces before and after “Test”, one should use `\begin{multipage}Test\end{multipage}` (on a single line).